# Any functions(or way) to check ExtJs page is completely rendered

Tags: extjs, selenium, selenium-rc, extjs3

I am using selenium to automate ExtJs(Ver 3) web application. My main challenge is, Wait for page(Elements) to be rendered. is there any build in function with Extjs or any javascript functions to verify the page is completely rendered. Currently i am managing with thread.sleep. But it sucks lots of execution time. I need a dynamic wait handler. Can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript we can make it. Here are two methods:

1. one is : document.readyState
2. another one is : document.body.readyState